# android play sound effect.

Tags: java, android, audio

i'm having trouble playing a sound in android.

My first attempt was all inside my onButtonClick function which worked really well for about 20 clicks. then the sound stopped. and i believe it used the entire sound pool of android because all my other apps stopped having sounds.

```
public void onButtonClick(View view)
{

MediaPlayer clickSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click);
clickSound.start();

//... other onButtonCode

}
```

i have since changed this up a little bit so that this is now a global variable

```
MediaPlayer clickSound;
```

and it is instantiated inside my onCreate() method. the onbuttonClick now has the clickSound.start() 
but this doesn't work the way i thought it should. the sound is seemingly random. sometimes the click will be there. sometimes there will be no sound. or sometimes the sound is there for a little blip  and ends before the sound is complete.  On the good side it doesn't seem to completely fill up the sound pool so i can keep getting 'some' sounds while i am testing.

What am i missing to make the sound function properly? 
I tried to add a `clickButton.stop()` but that made my sound not function at all, probably because it stops before it is noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

You should release the ressource after use.

```
clickSound.release();
clickSound = null;
```

---

I would suggest following:

Initialize the Player in onResume:

```
clickSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click);
```

Release ressources in onPause:

```
clickSound.release();
clickSound = null;
```

Use button to play sound:

```
clickSound.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) instead.

```
   soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, 0);
   resId = soundPool.load(context, R.raw.click, 1);
```

for play :

```
private void playSpecSound(int resId)
{
    if(soundPool != null)
    {
        if(0 == soundPool.play(resId, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, 1.0f))
        {
             Log.e(TAG, "Play specified sound failed !");
        }
    }
}
```